# Embed for music bot not working/discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm working on my music bot for my discord server. So my code from a technical perspective works, it can play music, and it has queues, but I'm trying to add embeds to the messages, but I keep getting an error message that my message, channel, author is not defined. How do correctly define properties that I need for my embeds to work?

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

const queue = new Map();

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ('skip', 'stop'),
    cooldown: 0,
    description: 'Advanced music bot',
    async execute(client, message, args, cmd, Discord){


        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voice_channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');

        const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

        if (cmd === 'play'){
            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
            let song = {};

            if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])) {
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = { title: song_info.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url }
            } else {
                const video_finder = async (query) =>{
                    const video_result = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (video_result.videos.length > 1) ? video_result.videos[0] : null;
                }

                const video = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
                if (video){
                    song = { title: video.title, url: video.url }
                } else {
                     message.channel.send('Error finding video.');
                }
            }

            if (!server_queue){

                const queue_constructor = {
                    voice_channel: voice_channel,
                    text_channel: message.channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: []
                }

                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push(song);

                try {
                    const connection = await voice_channel.join();
                    const Discord = require('discord.js');
                    queue_constructor.connection = connection;
                    video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send('There was an error connecting!');
                    throw err;
                }
            } else{
                server_queue.songs.push(song);
                newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("**Now adding...**")
                .setDescription(`${song.title}\n\`Requested by:\` ${message.author}`)
                .setColor("#ff0000")
                .setThumbnail('https://i.pinimg.com/474x/db/cd/d0/dbcdd0a38ebdb5f7f32cfda2f671dede.jpg')

                return message.channel.send


                message.channel.send(newEmbed);
            }
        }

    }
    
}

const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    song_queue.connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 0.5 })
    .on('finish', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
    await song_queue.text_channel.send
    newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("**Now playing...**")
    .setDescription(`${song.title}\n\`Requested by:\` ${message.author}`)
    .setColor("#ff0000")
    .setThumbnail('https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a1/57/2c/a1572c4306f27fd644ab62199def8aab.jpg')

    message.channel.send(newEmbed);
}
```

Comment: Can you please reduce your code and make it in the JavaScript format? It’s best to reduce it to around where you get the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the **const** before the "newEmbed" and you also can't have "newEmbed" twice, as it will return an error. Change it. E.g.

```
const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

Or you can have

```
const songList = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

The **songList** can be anything but just not the same for the other embeds you want.

Comment: This did help for sure, and thank you for pointing that out, but I'm still getting the error

ReferenceError: message is not defined